# How to draw a canvas bitmap image at one of two locations randomly?

Tags: java, android, canvas, random, android-canvas

How to draw a bitmap at either one  of two random positions?
I wanna draw a bitmap image at either

1. at a point which is in center from one side of screen and from center of the screen
2. or at center from other side

like as show by the dots below

```
 ______________________
|     .     |     .    |             
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|Typical android screen|
|           |          |
________________________
```

Here's how tried to attain it but failed

```
//package and import
public class items extends View {
   //here declared to some variables
    private int RandomSing;
    Point center;
    public items(int color, Context c) {
        super(c);

        // create a bitmap from the supplied image (the image is the icon that is part of the app)
      items= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(),
                R.drawable.rocket),dst,dst, false);


    }
    public void setBounds(int lx, int ly, int ux, int uy) {
        lowerX = lx;
        lowerY = ly;
        upperX = ux;
        upperY = uy;
        x = y = 0;
        center=new Point(0,0);
        RandomSing=0;
    }
    public boolean move() {
    // use to move the bitmap in vertical direction downwards 
        y += stepY;

        if(stepY<8){stepY+=0.0025;}

        if (y + dst > upperY) {
            x = y = 0 ;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void reset() {
        x=0;
        RandomSing +=7;
        y=0;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.draw(canvas);
        X=getWidth();
        Y=getHeight();
        center=new Point((int)(X/4),0 );
        if(RandomSing%2!=0) x = (dst +center.x );
        else x = (dst+center.x+(X/2));
        canvas.drawBitmap(items,x,y, null);
    }
}
```

actually I will use it in another class to use it as alien ships coming to attack 
but it only come at on the first dot..

Please give me as many details as you can

Comment: How many times are you calling `setBounds()`, and how many times are you calling `reset()`, and what is `dst`?

Comment: Again thanks. SetBounds is called once (in override method Onsize changed) and reset is called when the items reached the bottom of screen or intersects with bullets as part of game ... Dst is just the width and height of scaled bitmap .... Actually reset(literal meaning) method is used to give value to coordinates ...

Comment: You have answered me before and in that question I have given a Java class named GameView .. There's where all these functions are called . If you want I can even add it here..

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't notice that. It's interesting, b/c it looks like it should work. I will have to look at it some more. Are you sure `reset()` is executing exactly once when a bullet hits it?

Comment: No,  reset runs when there's a need to reDraw the bitmap like I told you when it reaches the bottom of screen or it intersects with a bullet so it makes y=0 and x =0 and assign a new random value but I think I should assign the value of x ( x = getwidth()/4) or (x = 3*getwidth ()/4)  in reset function only ... Hope you understand..

Comment: So, tell me, what happens if you replace `x = y = 0 ;` (in `move()`) with a call to `reset()`?

Comment: Same , move() checks that bitmap is at bottom or not and if it's true it will itself reset the value or call reset function .           
                                                                    Actually instead of  x=y=0 in reset I think I should provide thecode which changes the value of coordinates of bitmap y=0 and x = (shown above) but the problem I am facing is of positioning it and than randomise those two positions in reset

Comment: Earlier I tried this in reset                                                             ....  y=0;.                                                          RandomSingh=(int) (100*Math.Random());.                X=(RandomSingh%2==0)?(dst+wh/4):(dst+3*wh/4);.                   where wh was the getwidth() of canvas drawn.... and dst width and height of bitmap   And no initialization  in onDraw() method but only first case(dst+wh/4 ) falls ...

Comment: "...instead of x=y=0 in reset I think I should provide thecode..." Sounds like a good idea to me. Your `Math.random()` code looks good too. I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I recommend using a breakpoint and stepping through the code that calls `Math.Random()`.

Comment: I will try it and will report you if there is something to be told ...  Although thank you for all your help...